# Combine Rows if a Cell Value is Shared

Tags: python, excel, vba

I am creating a csv that will serve as a reference for acceptable nicknames for any given name.  I then take an input name, look through each row to see if that name exists, and then return all other cells in the row, which are the nicknames. The input name does not have to be in the first column to have results returned.  However, I created the list from a few different sources, and now I have duplicates. 
Is there a way to combine each row if any of the cells match up?

Solutions in Excel/VBA/Python would be great.

Example rows from csv:

```
a       b       c       d
steven  steve       
abigail abby    abby    gail
stephen steve   steph   
abraham ab      abe
```

Desired output:

```
a       b       c       d
steven  steve  stephen  steph   
abigail abby    abby    gail
abraham ab      abe
```

Comment: You have two "abby"s in the third row. Probably an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My proposed solution may seem unusual at the first glance, but it works.

You can build a graph of names where two names are connected if they are mutually acceptable nicknames. The connected components of the graph are groups of all mutually acceptable nicknames.

Start by importing `networkx` (network manipulation module) and other support tools:

```
import networkx as nx
from itertools import combinations, chain
```

Here's a list of lists from the CSV file:

```
names = [['steven', 'steve'], ['abigail', 'abby', 'abby', 'gail'],
         ['stephen', 'steve', 'steph'], ['abraham', 'ab', 'abe']]
```

Create a list of edges by connecting each name in each sublist with each other name in the same sublist:

```
edges = chain.from_iterable(combinations(set(n), 2) for n in names)
```

Construct a graph from the edge list:

```
G = nx.Graph(edges)
```

Identify connected components:

```
[list(n) for n in nx.connected_components(G)]
#[['stephen', 'steph', 'steven', 'steve'],
# ['gail', 'abigail', 'abby'], 
# ['abe', 'ab', 'abraham']]
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! The one change I made was using the itertools method combinations_with_replacement instead of combinations, because I had some 1 cell rows.